# How to change Floating Action button shadow colour

Tags: android, button, action, floating

I want to change Floating Action button **shadow colour** from **black/grey** to **colorprimary/custom color of shadow ** shadow example like below image with **center blue FAB button** with light **blue shadow** not grey shadow. But we can change the FAB button background color. But as you can see in image there is **blue shadow of FAB button**.I want to achive that thing.

[image]

Comment: Please more info and write xml and code .

Comment: @ahmad aghazadeh See I have updated my code and attached image. see in that center bottom blue FAB button is with light blue shadow not gery.I want to achieve that

Comment: there i no xml code done yet. just assume there is normal layout with Floating action button. That screen change FAB button shadow color change property needed.

Answer (score 2):

**try this** :: `app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccentGrey"`

where **colorAccentGrey = YourColor**

and **put** `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` **at the beginning of the XML** if you forggt,

and **for Remove shadow** :: `app:elevation="0dp"`

Hope this will help you.. :)

Comment: no this will not help. it just change FAB button background colour not the shadow color.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have 2 options:

1. as @Uttam said, change the elevation of the FAB widget
2. to make a custom design and embed it as an image in your layout as shown here http://androidgifts.com/android-material-design-floating-action-button-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

None of the answer worked for me. So i worked this. anyhow it will give shadow like effect that enough for me

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_black"
        app:elevation="0dp" // disable outside shawdow
        app:borderWidth="30dp" // make borderwidth to 25dp or height of fab
        app:backgroundTint="#00E5FF" // now you will see only this color with shawdow 
        android:backgroundTint="#00E5FF" // since border is 30dp u ll not see this color and if you want to check reduce border width to 25dp then ull see this color in center as a small dot.
        />
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to remove the stroke(border-width), the default value is 0.5dp change it to 0dp, that is

```xml
app:borderWidth="0dp"
```

Refer Regular and mini FAB key properties in Material Design documentation!

Link - https://material.io/components/buttons-floating-action-button/android

Answer (score 0):

Late but I got the solution. Let's get started:

1. make a custom background shape for shadow in **res/drawable** folder names as **shadow_bg**. And paste below code in it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape android:shape="oval" 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient android:type="radial"
        android:startColor="@color/black"
        android:endColor="@android:color/transparent"
        android:gradientRadius="50dp"/>
    </shape>
```

where **startColor** will be your shadow color. I am keeping black here.

2. make your activity's parent layout to CoordinatorLayout and then make a fab(Floating Action Button) and a view for shadow of fab button like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
       <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_gravity="center"
           android:id="@+id/fab"
           android:src="@drawable/ic_add"/>
        <View
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="@drawable/shadow_bg"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/fab"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp"/>
    
        </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This will show like this :

[image]

Enjoy. You're good to go.